# What triggers Source Server to run the embedded command to get a copy of a source file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, version-control, perforce

I'm trying to setup source indexing using Visual Studio 2010, and the included perl scripts from the Windows SDK (in my case, Windows 8) using Perforce as the source control

For Windows 8 SDk
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\srcsrv

From Bruce Dawsons blog (linked below), it may be located here for older sdks
C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\srcsrv

---

My pdb's are getting indexed, and manually looking at the pdbs, as well as running the following command will extract the source files correctly.

```
srctool -x test.pdb
```

This may be a misunderstanding of how this is tied into Visual Studio, but **my problem** is related to local edits to files.

1. If I delete a file and start the debugger

   - VS will pop up a dialog asking me to confirm that I want to run the command and will properly download and open the source file and I can continue debugging
2. If I edit or sync a different version of a file so it doesn't match the pdb

   - I don't get this dialog, and as a result, VS displays the "No Source Available" window

From the MSDN site (also linked below):

> *When there is no source code on the local machine or **the PDB file does not match the source code**, you can use Source Server to help debug an application*

It seems that this second case, should cause VS to run the command to get the source, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  Case #1 is working how I'd expect, but I need to get case #2 working before this is useful.  Also, I've enabled the "Print source server diagnostics to the Output window" and I don't get any errors or warnings.

Should this second case trigger a download of the version of the source file when the pdb was indexed? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks!

*edit*
This works as I expect in windbg, so this seems to be specific to Visual Studio

References:
http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/11/08/source-indexing-is-underused-awesomeness/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms242029(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for identifying this issue. We have fixed the problem, and the change will be reflected in future releases of Visual Studio (not in updates to 2013). We hope this fix improves your experience with our tools and technologies. 
Specifically we have modified the behavior of the debugger to match what WinDbg does in this case. We will allow you to download the matching source file from the source server if the temporary file on disk doesn't match with what you are debugging.